# How to change position Save/Cancel Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: gnome, 17.10, accessibility

The save dialog, position Save/Cancel button on the upper part of the window, cancel on the left and save on the right.

[image: Save dialog screenshot]

I saw a big controversy about the position of close/minimize/maximize buttons, but anything about this change. It doesn't seem very helpful in terms of usability (my opinion, of course).

Is it possible to bring down these buttons?